# Is there any way for me to run my own instance of a Google Wave server?

Tags: google-wave

Does anyone think there is or will be a way for an entity to run their own private/firewalled Google Wave server?

Does their claim to open source Google Wave point in this direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Google has said they intend to release an open source Wave platform and intend for people to run their own server and to roll their own clients.

Check out the video at [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_UyVmITiYQ) they go into quite a bit of detail about it.

Answer (score 4):

The [Wave Protocol web site](http://www.waveprotocol.org/) will have all of the information and specifications needed to build your own Wave server.  Whether you decide to make it available to talk to others is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 4):

### Update November 3, 2009

Google has just released a [preliminary version of the server](http://googlewavedev.blogspot.com/2009/11/wavesandboxcom-federate-this.html) software required.  You'll also need to run an XMPP server for the Wave server to plug in to - one that is known to work is suggested in the installation instructions.

[Detailed installation instructions](http://code.google.com/p/wave-protocol/wiki/Installation) cover OSX and Linux. While it should be usable on Windows (it's Java based), some are reporting problems with it, and the instructions for windows installation that were available yesterday were removed.

Perhaps in a year or two we'll see wave servers implemented in other languages, but for now you are required to have a java capable server.  Given the other requirements of the protocol you'll almost surely need VPS or dedicated hosting if you aren't hosting your own machines already.  Many developers are running them in virtual machines for testing.

-Adam